# How do you auto arrange program panes in Ubuntu GNOME

Tags: 14.04, gnome

How do I get all the open windows to auto arrange. I can see that ctrl+cmd+(up/down/left/right) has control over a single pane.

What I am after is something similar to windows where it can auto arrange all the open windows or 'cascade' them.